# I've a problem with connecting my online hosted MySQL database with my C# application

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a database hosted for free on 000webhost.com and I'm trying to connect this database to my C# application. When I created the database on 000webhost it gave me this table that I used while building my connection string
[image]

And this is my connection string

```
Server=99.000webhost.io; Database=db_name_that_in_the_table; port=3306; Uid=username_that_in_the_table; Pwd=the_password_i_used_in_phpmyadmin; SSLMode=Preferred
```

And this is my C# code

```
 try
        {
            string myconn = "Server=99.000webhost.io; Database=db_name_that_in_the_table; port=3306; Uid=username_that_in_the_table; Pwd=the_password_i_used_in_phpmyadmin; SSLMode=Preferred";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myconn);
            conn.Open();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

When I try to establish the connection I got this error

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

PS: I got the hostname or the server name and the port from the variables tab in phpMyAdmin.

What is the problem and how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does that webhost provide that kind of access; many hosts restrict database connections to the server to only from within the hosting system for security reasons.

Comment: @Uueerdo I don't know, do you know how to ensure?

Comment: You'd probably need to check with the hosting company, or see if they have an faq. Just found this with a quick google [link to finding](https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-from-my-computer-27)

Comment: @Uueerdo you're right, that's the reason. 000webhost doesn't support remote connections.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 000webhost.com doesn't support MySQL remote connections. Thanks to @Uueerdo, he pointed me to google about that.

Comment: @E.Mamaghani what settings?